# How to fit a custom non-linear model in python

Tags: python, math, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-functions

Suppose, i want to find those parameters `w`, that  minimize MAE or MSE 
of model `y(x,z)`:

`y = (w_1 * x_1 + ... + w_n * x_n) / (w_1 * z_1 + ... + w_n * z_n)`

How can i do it in python?

Comment: [scipy.optimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html). If you have `n` variables x and `n` variables z, you can let the independent variable `X` have `2n` rows and the columns should be the observations for each variable.

In this way, `X` is a 2-D array of rows 2n and columns M. Also the parameters we want to predict are in an array w of length `n`. Thus way, the function by OP is expressed as:

```
y = w@x/w@z = w@X[:n, :]/w@X[n:, :]
```

where `@` is matrix multiplication in `numpy`. Here is the full code:

```
def my_model(x, *args):
  N, _ = x.shape
  w = np.array(args)
  # assuming x and z have same number of variables = N/2
  y = w@x[:N//2, :] / (w@x[N//2:, :])
  return y

popts, pcov = curve_fit(my_model, x, y)
```

where `popts` contains all the optimized w variables.

Comment: can you please explain this line: `y = w@x[:N//2, :] / (w@x[N//2:, :])`

Comment: x has shape N X M, where N is # of rows,  and each row contains one of the variables x_1, ... x_n, z_1, ..., z_n , so that N =  2 *n. So I am assuming the first n rows contain x variables and last n rows contain z variables. Also the @ operator is just matrix multiplication. so w@x[:N//2, :] = w_1 * x_1 + ...+ w_n * x_n. Note this considers the case where each x_i and z_i is of length M, where are the observations (# of cols in x)...

Comment: I modified my answer a bit.